# retrive multiple value from a single row in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView. Each row of its has multiple items like two TextView. I also have an custom Array adapter. I retrieved the first item of a row using `getListAdapter().getItem(position)`. But failed to retrieve the next one. How can I do this ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Cursor from your ListView like :

```
Cursor CursorGetListItem = (Cursor)YourList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

then you can access your ListView Columns like :

```
CursorGetListItem.getString(CursorGetListItem.getColumnIndex(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME));
CursorGetListItem.getString(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

each row in the listview has a layout

supposedly you do

```
view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, null);
```

now you can find each of your "sub-items" as they are declaredin this listview layout:

```
TextView tv1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1)
TextView tv2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to retrieve value from your textview? But if you are talking about edittext.

Be careful, if your listview is long enough your view component may get recycled. In this case the best you can do is to build the underline data structure by yourself and add a listener to each editable view you want to extract information. You can refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127524/the-content-of-edittext-contained-into-a-android-listview-isnt-saved).And you can do something similar to other widgets.

If you do want to put a edittext inside a listview, my suggestion is dont, as the focus on edittext inside a listview is really hard to control (I have tried this for couple days and switch to scroll view in the end).