# Android listView cell recycling with variable-sized cells

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView.  The cells have variable height.  That causes a problem when recycling cells -- the recycled cells may have the wrong height.  Turning off recycling makes scrolling too choppy.  How can I get the heights correct while still recycling the cells?

EDIT: the heights vary all over the place.  There is not a short list of possible values.

Comment: Does every row have a different size? Or even when you have different heights, you know how much different heights will you have?

Comment: did you use getitemviewtype?

Comment: I do not think there is a solution to your problem (infinite different types + recycling). Anyway I upvoted the question so let's see if some interesting answer comes up

Comment: I don't understand how it is possible to have large number of types without needing to reference each type ? Is that a real case or an hypothetical case ? can you give more details ?

Comment: The height depends on the height of the text in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

**TWO CELL TYPE**

Usually the problem comes from the getView. I am not sure what you are really looking for because you don't provide your custom adapter. However, I give you an example with 2 different cell types, but the cell contains only a textview.

In that case all the cells are fully adjusted with the recycling. Read carefully and extend/modify to match your needs.

in your `CustomAdapter`

```
private final class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //the fastest is to get the layout inflater once and not each time getView is called
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    ...

    //here depending on the item position determine if cell is of type 1 or 2
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (/* your type 1 criteria is match */) {
            return TYPE_1;
        } else {
            return TYPE_2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_1:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_of_type_1, parent, false);
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_type_1);
                    break;
                case TYPE_2:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_of_type_2, parent, false);
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_type_2);
                    break;
             }
             convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }

         //get the text for that specific cell and set it
         holder.text.setText(getMyCustomTextForThisCell());

         return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {     
    TextView text;
}
```

---

**SINGLE CELL TYPE**

In the case you simply need a cell of one type with a single textview in it and want to put text of different length in all the cell and the cell adapt its height automatically simply use the following code in your `CustomAdapter`

```
private final class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //the fastest is to get the layout inflater once and not each time getView is called
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_type, parent, false);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_in_your_row);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //get the text for that specific cell and set it
        holder.text.setText(getMyCustomTextForThisCell());

        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {     
    TextView text;
}
```

---

**CELL LAYOUT**

In the example I give the file row_type.xml (the layout file of your row) should look like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview_in_your_row"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

don't forget the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`or else the cell won't resize

---

**SIDE COMMENT**

This side comment does not talk about the OP question, however if people come here because of the **cell recycling** words in the title they could be interested in the fact that I give a full example of recycling cells with an EditText here

[The content of EditText contained into a Android ListView isn't saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127524/the-content-of-edittext-contained-into-a-android-listview-isnt-saved/19130861#19130861)

Comment: Your approach would be the way to go **IF** the OP hadn't added:
"the heights vary all over the place. There is not a short list of possible values."

Comment: I don't get the point there. What does he mean by "vary all over the place". I mean, I first had problem with recycling with only 1 type as I was not doing setTag at the correct place.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I suspect he means that all the views can have different types. Since two views need have the same type to be converted in one another, if all of them have different types then the recycling would accomplish nothing

Comment: They are all the same type, in the sense that their contents are the same kind of thing.  However, depending on the length of the text, the height could be quite tall or quite short.

Comment: So if i understand correcly, you have a cell with a textview and want to display text but every cell has a text of different length ? If that's it, that is exactly what my code does. Remove the second type and use only one and it works. The thing for the reuse is to get the tag and set the tag at the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it using Xamarin.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        int type = GetItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_row_layout, parent, false);
            holder.myTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.viewRow);
            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag;
            int heightWeWant = heights[type];
            if (holder.myTextView.Height != heightWeWant) //height we have isn't what we want
            {
                AbsListView.LayoutParams parms = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, heightWeWant); //Width, Height //resize the view to the height we want
                convertView.LayoutParameters = parms;
            }
            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }

        holder.myText = "Some text here";

        return convertView;
    }
```